# Проблемы с пользователями MariaDB в терминале. Не видит базы данных

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, mariadb, xampp

После того, как я подключаюсь к БД(MariaDB) через терминал с помощью `./mysql -uПользователь -pМойпароль` в `/opt/lampp/bin`, то пишет:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

При этом если не вводить `-p`, то есть входить без пароля, то заходит нормально. Но при этом не показываются базы данных.
В случае же , если логиниться как `root`, то проблем не возникает и показываются все созданные в phpmyadmin базы данных. Если же под рутом использовать команду: `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'username' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`, то ничего не меняется. То есть, зайдет(и то только без пароля) и не будут видны базы данных.

XAMPP бывает включен.

Comment: Так какое у вас имя пользователя? username или User? Кажется вы просто что-то напутали при вводе имени пользователя и пароля.

Comment: Нее, имя пользователя и пароль правильно ввожу. Много раз перепроверял. Даже новые создавал аккаунты. Все равно никак

Comment: А как пользователя создаёте?

Comment: Пробовал по-разному: 1) Через CREATE USER 'имя_пользователя'@'хост' IDENTIFIED BY 'пароль'.  И потом уже GRANT ... 2) Создавал через GRANT тоже(без предварительного создания через CREATE). Заканчивал все, конечно, FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась следующим образом: при создании пользователя БД посредством команды `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` нужно явным образом прописывать хост. Т.е. вместо `'username'@'%'` нужно было писать `'username'@'localhost'` и после уже пароль. Видимо, такое поведение прописано где-то в `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`